# How to make a "Dashboard" screen?

Tags: iphone

Is there some easy way to implement the gui design pattern "Dashboard", with badges on the icons, as described in http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html on the iphone?

Like in the official facebook app for iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the open source library Three20 and its TTLauncherView is the answer. http://three20.info/overview